# Is this a valid way to shrink an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to take an array of size `N` and shrink it to an array of size `M`, without unnecessary copying back and forth. Is the following valid? I tried executing the code and it works. But I want to know if this is right and in general and is not compiler dependent.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int N   =       atoi(argv[1]);
        int M   =       atoi(argv[2]);
        double* a       =       new double[N];
        double RANDMAX  =       RAND_MAX;
        std::cout << "Displaying 'a'..." << std::endl;
        for (int k=0; k<N; ++k) {
                a[k]    =       rand()/RANDMAX;
                std::cout << a[k] << std::endl;
        }
        double* b       =       new double[M];
        b       =       a;
        delete [] a;
        std::cout << "Displaying 'b'..." << std::endl;
        for (int k=0; k<M; ++k) {
                std::cout << b[k] << std::endl;
        }
        delete [] b;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean my `shrink`?  Do you mean throw away every n'th element?  Or just keep the first M elements?

Comment: @PeterM I just want to keep the first `M` elements.

Comment: So in effect you want do `deallocate` memory after the M'th element?  But don't want to copy any data around?

Comment: I believe that you can't do it if you are using `new` and `delete`.  With `malloc` you could `realloc`

Comment: @PeterM Thanks. This is useful. Could you kindly add a short snippet of the appropriate code?

Comment: See david.pfx's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you leaked the memory initially allocated for b

```
double *b = new double[M];
b = a; // the memory initially pointed by b is lost ...
```

Also this way you are deleting the same memory location twice (Paranaix posted this already) and purely out of luck, you program keeps running.

Here's a valid solution

```
int Num(3), shrunkNum(2);

double *a = (double*)malloc(Num*sizeof(double));
a[0] = 0;
a[1] = 1;
a[2] = 2;
// realloc shrinks memory after copying the contents up to the new size
a         = (double*)realloc(a, shrunkNum*sizeof(double));

for (int i(0); i < shrunkNum; ++i)
{
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
}

free(a); // how to delete the block pointed by a
```

Beware that `realloc` does not work with memory allocated with `new`.

That been said **we rarely reallocate downwards**. Just keeping track of how many elements are present is enough. See eg what the STL does with vector, where resizing to a smaller size will reduce size, but [the capacity remains the same](http://ideone.com/U9tPMv).

Comment: Thanks. I did not know this can be done with malloc and realloc. Thanks Nikos and Peter M.

Comment: Dont forget to use placement new with non primitive types!

Comment: If the type is not trivial then you can't use `realloc` anyway.

Comment: Thanks Nikos. But in my case, memory could be critical. The reason for reallocating downwards is I only know an upper bound on the size before hand. Also, I do not want to use `vector`.

Comment: Also, I read from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) that realloc doesn't copy the content(which is what I want).

Comment: It says **The content of the memory block is preserved up to the lesser of the new and old sizes, even if the block is moved to a new location.** . It does what you want, you can try the [example](http://ideone.com/PFOr3P) I posted

Answer (score 5):

```
    b = a;
    delete[] a;
```

Using `b` or `a` after this is UB, as `b` points to the same array/location as `a`. They represent the same array after the assignment. Thus `delete[] b;` is also UB as you delete the array twice.

Comment: My naive C++ knowledge states that every new must be paired with a delete. So, in which case, don't we need `delete [] b`?

Comment: @LeslieFaulkner You already deleted it with `delete[] a;`. b points to the same array as a after the assignment

Comment: @LeslieFaulkner: does your naive knowledge tell you that `b = new double[M]; b = something else;` is a memory leak? Because it is one. You've lost the address of the array you just allocated, so you *cannot* any longer pair it with `delete[]` of that array.

Comment: @LeslieFaulkner You indeed need another `delete []` for the `new []` in line that introduces `b`, but the pointer you'd need for that is lost on `a = b;`. You have a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

No, as mentioned elsewhere, this code is wrong and in fact there is no combination of these operations (new, delete) that will achieve your purpose without copying the data.

There is a function realloc() which does exactly what you want, but you should only use it on memory allocated with malloc().

The standard library functions such as vector have the ability to reallocate. This is the preferred way to do what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you do is undefined behavior.

First, the array you assign in the line `double* b = new double[M];` will never be released, because you reassign the only pointer to that memory right in the next line. (`b = a;`). That's a classical memory leak.

Second, in the next line `delete [] a;`  you delete the array to which both `a` and `b` point. That means both a and b now point to released memory which can be reallocated at any time and can then be overwritten by completely unrelated data.